# Lock with small overhead or lockless

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a ConcurrentQueue that gets filled with objects from one thread and another thread takes objects from it and processes them.

If the queue gets big i can "compress" it by removing duplicates. The compressing takes the queue and makes it into a list, iterates through it and creates a new queue that only have distinct values. So I replace the queue, and since i do that i cant have objects inserted into the queue that gets overwritten, i will loose them.

My problem is if i add a lock(obj) {} or some sort of LockHandle i loose alot of performance. There are a lot of transactions but processing time is very low, so locking looks like what is killing my performance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace A
{
    public abstract class Base
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<Data> unProcessed = new ConcurrentQueue<Data>();

        private const int MIN_COLLAPSETIME = 30;
        private const int MIN_COLLAPSECOUNT = 1000;
        private QueueCollapser Collapser;
        private ManualResetEventSlim waitForCollapsing = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
        private ManualResetEventSlim waitForWrite = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        // Thread signal.
        public AutoResetEvent unProcessedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        // exiting
        public volatile bool Exiting = false;

        private Task task;

        public BasePusher()
        {
            // initiate Collapser
            Collapser = new QueueCollapser();
            // set up thread
            task = new Task(
               () =>
               {
                   consumerTask();
               }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
               );

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            task.Start();
        }

        private void consumerTask()
        {
            Data data = null;
            while (!Exiting)
            {
                try
                {
                        // do we try to collapse
                        if (unProcessed.Count > MIN_COLLAPSECOUNT && (DateTime.Now - Collapser.LastCollapse).TotalSeconds > MIN_COLLAPSETIME)
                        {
                            waitForCollapsing.Reset();
                            waitForWrite.Wait();
                            unProcessed = Collapser.Collapse(unProcessed);
                            waitForCollapsing.Set();
                            // tried this aswell instead of using my own locking, this is like Monitor.Enter
                            lock(this) {
                                unProcessed = Collapser.Collapse(unProcessed);
                            }
                        }
                        if (sum == 0)
                        {
                            // we wake the thread after 20 seconds, if nothing is in queue it will just go back and wait
                            unProcessedEvent.WaitOne(20000);
                        }
                        var gotOne = unProcessed.TryDequeue(out data);
                        if (gotOne)
                        {
                            ProcessTime(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        protected abstract void ProcessTime(Data d);

        public void AddToQueue(Data d)
        {
            waitForCollapsing.Wait();
            waitForWrite.Reset();
            unProcessed.Enqueue(d);
            waitForWrite.Set();
            unProcessedEvent.Set();
        }

        // tried this aswell instead of using my own locking, this is like Monitor.Enter
        public void AddToQueueAlternate(Data d)
        {
            lock(this) {
                unProcessed.Enqueue(d);
                waitForWrite.Set();
                unProcessedEvent.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done without locking?
Can i use a more lightweight lock? As of now there is only one thread adding data and one thread reading. And i can keep it that way if that gets me a better lock.

Comment: Your consumer is too slow.  So it doesn't make sense to make it slower by having it look for duplicates.  Let the producer do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want concurrency and no duplicates, you should use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So redeclare your Queue:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Data, Data> unProcessed = 
   new ConcurrentDictionary<Data, Data>();
```

This will considerably simplify your code while keeping very good performances.

Comment: Would this also let me keep the order?

Comment: No it would not, a dictionary is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have duplicates?

If the publisher can really add duplicates then you need some type of concurrent hashing object (`Dictionary` or `HashSet`) to detect and prevent this from ocurring in the publisher.

You may also want to investigate [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Comment: Well it is not exactly duplicates. This is objects that will be written to a database. The "duplicats" i remove is the ones with the same primary key. I do .... ON EXISTING UPDATE and i remove the ones that will be overwritten anyways